# Autohide div onclick

Tags: jquery, animation, html, onclick

Hello I was looking for a script to show/hide a div and I found this one which I tweaked a little bit but works perfectly.

```
$(function() {
$(".activities a").click(function(e) {
    $('.search').html('<center><img src="images/loading.gif" style="margin: 20px 0;" /></center>');
    $(".search").toggle().toggleClass("active");
    $('.search').load('someurlhere.php');
    e.stopPropagation();
});


$(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
});

$(".search").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

});

this will allow any link inside a div called activities to toggle a div called search. Works perfect but I wanted to know how to make this universal ie have this script work for any link? Do I have to create a function out of this and assign it to the link?

Answer (score 2):

you could bind to the body element

```
$("#title").click(function(event){
   $("#mailbody").toggle();
     event.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function(){
    $("#mailbody").hide();
});
```

Comment: hi Dave, thanks for the response! I tried your script but it's working. I would like it to work exactly as it is at the moment but only make it disappear not ONLY when you click on the title tag but anywhere on the screen EXCEPT when you click the scrollbar to scroll the page!!!

Comment: hi Jay sorry I'm a bit confused by your comment, when the user clicks anywhere on the page i.e the body, do you want the mailbody to toggle or just hide? or is this solution not working at all for you?

Comment: i just want it to hide!!! you click on the item named 'title' to open it...but you can click on the 'title' or body to close it

Comment: @Jay i have updated my answer, i tested this locally and it seems to do what you need, you will need both bindings in your script. let me know how it goes.

Comment: still not working Dave :) what happens now is that when you click anywhere on the body, it shows the div and when you click again it hides it. maybe it's got to do with the .toggle()? Also updated the script http://jsfiddle.net/WsjV2/4/ how do you make sure each element targets it's own div?

Comment: @Jay sorry I made a copy paste error, have re-updated the code the body event should should call hide(). my bad.

Comment: hello @Dave I just realized a little problem with the hide script. When you right-click inside the div, it still disappears...can this be corrected?